# Finding close road centerlines to given trajectory

Tags: python, point, line, shapely

I am working on trajectory prediction model for autonomous vehicle using previous trajectory and road information.

I have lane centerlines. I need to filter them. (Removing unnecessary lanes). I filter most of the unnecessary lanes by making Region of Interest(ROI).

But I need help with filtering lanes in opposite direction and perpendicular lanes in road intersections.

> My current method (using Python shapely)

```
def filter(candidate_cl, trajectory):
    # This function is called after lanes are filtered with ROI

    check = lambda traj_start, traj_end, line_start, line_end:
    distance(traj_start, line_start)<=distance(traj_end, line_start) and distance(traj_start, line_end)>=distance(traj_end, line_end)

    return [ line for line in candidate_cl if check(trajectory[0], trajectory[-1], line[0], line[-1])]
```

Basically checking if start of trajectory is close to start of line and end of the trajectory is close to end of end of line

Here are the examples

> Description: light green and red lines are trajectory, purple line is
>   selected lane(green dot is start of lane and purple is the end) and green-yellowish rectangle is ROI

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

In first example filtering good enough, But in example 2, It doesn't remove some lanes from intersection

> Is there any way existing method to find for this problem or any tips to improve my current method?